# My jquery code is running the first page but not the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please focus the "YAB Network" link in footer. It needs to run a tooltip.  I'm using [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html) library.
[First site](http://oyunparkigruplari.com).
[Second site](http://isguvenlik.gen.tr).

Both need to be the same. My code is running in first site but not running in the second site. Why? What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second site cannot load the jQuery core library file:

`GET http://isguvenlik.gen.tr/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js 404 (Not Found)`

Make sure the correct path is entered there or use a Google jQuery CDN url from here:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide